# Npm is not working in visual studio code but works in cmd

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm

[image]

theres no any error or anything..

i tried everything its working only in CMD but int PS not working. I tried everything but still its not working. Do you have any idea how to run npm in the VSC. It was wokring earlier..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things you can try:

1. Run `echo %PATH%` in CMD and compare it to the environment variables configured in Visual Studio Code.
2. Verify you node and npm version by running node -v and npm -v in CMD to check the installed versions.
3. Finally, make sure that Visual Studio Code is configured to use the correct terminal shell. You can check this by navigating to:

   File > Preferences > Settings

   Search for "terminal shell", and ensure that the correct shell is
   selected.